# How does the gravitational potential change when using physical instead of comoving coordinates?

Tags: cosmology, gravity, space-expansion

If we consider the universe as filled by a self-gravitating fluid, then there will exist an associated gravitational potential $\phi$ and the Poisson equation $\nabla^2=4\pi Ga^2\rho$ will hold, where $\rho$ is the total density of the fluid.

However, if we want to also consider the expansion of the universe, we need to change from comoving coordinates $\vec{x}$ to physical coordinates $\vec{r}=a\vec{x}$, where $a$ is the scale factor that measures the expansion.

How does the gravitational potential change when we do this?

My attempt at a reasoning is the following:

$$\phi_x=-G\int_V\dfrac{1}{x}dx=-G\int_{V/a^3}a\dfrac{1}{r}\dfrac{1}{a}dr=-G\int_{V/a^3}\dfrac{1}{r}dr$$

where $V$ is the volume enclosed by the fluid and I have used that $\vec{r}=a\vec{x}\ \ \Rightarrow\ \ r=ax\ \ \Rightarrow\ \ dr=adx$.

But I can't see how to proceed, and this might not be the way to see how the gravitational potential changes. Any ideas? Thank you very much in advance!